# Percentage help for my slider program.

Tags: percentile

I'm trying to create a program which allows the user to enter in any number of values, where each value can be any number.  For example, the user may choose to enter the following 4 values:

```
-478.93
485.44
569.48
593.82
```

What formula do I need to use to get the slider in the program to show -478.93 when the slider is at the 0% position and 593.82 when the slider is at the 100% position? The slider should show the correct value at all other percentages.

For example, when at the 50% position, it should show 292.4525, which is the average of the values entered in by the user:

```
292.4525 = ( -478.93 + 485.44 + 569.48 + 593.82 ) / 4
```

Comment: I was about to post my answer when you erased last time.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the previous question was too long and unclear.  Any chance of getting back to your answers text using the browsers back button to copy the text?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I still have my spreadsheet data... why now you have a negative value?

Comment: I have the negative value to show that the user can type in any value and any number of values too, not just 4 values and not just positive values.

Comment: Ok, because you assume all data must fit in that range, 50% will not be near 289.20, it will actually be at 57.445

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake.  1 second.

Comment: I used the following to get that 50% value: 292.4525 = ( -478.93 + 485.44 + 569.48 + 593.82 ) / 4.  It's slightly different from what I had their originally.  Not sure how I ended up with that 289.20.

Comment: Ok, if you want a linear response, the 50% mark will not match the average of the samples.

Comment: Any other solutions/formulas I can use to achieve my end result?  Basically 0% = -478.93, 50% = 292.4525, 100% = 593.82.  50% will be the average of the values entered by the user.  All other percentages should act accordingly.

Comment: You will need two slopes: one for 0 to 50% and the sencond for 50% to 100%.

Comment: +1 for the 2 slope idea.  I'll give that a try!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the minimal value (here $a=-478.93$), $c$ the maximal value (here $c=593.82$) and $b$ the average (here $b=292.4525$). Then let the percentage $x$ ($0\le x\le 100$) correspond to

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}a+\frac x{50}(b-a)&\text{if }0\le x\le 50\\
2b-c+\frac x{50}(c-b)&\text{if }50\le x\le 100\end{cases}$$
(This corresponds to CAGT's suggestion of two slopes).